# How to get values by matching column names in a dataframe with another dataframe and use the values to calculate additional values?

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

I have a dataframe `mat` which is a sample by gene matrix, which contains either values `1, -1 or 0`, such as:

```
          Gene1    Gene2      Gene5      Gene7 
 Sample1    1        0         -1         1
 Sample2    0       -1          0         1
 Sample3   -1        0          1         1
 Sample4    1        1          0         0
```

Another dataframe `score` contains the corresponding scores for all the genes, such as:

```
GeneName       Score
 Gene1          0.5
 Gene2          0.3
 Gene3          0.2
 Gene4          0.6
 Gene5          0.7
 Gene6          0.1
 Gene7          0.4
```

What I am trying to do is to get a new column in `mat`, which will contain some scores based on an equation. The equation is:

For each row, `mat[1,1]`*score of `Gene1`+ `mat[1,2]`*score of `Gene2`+ `mat[1,3]`*score of `Gene5`+ `mat[1,4]`*value of `Gene7`. Same for every row of `mat`.

For example, for first row in the given data, the result for `Sample1` will be:

```
(1*0.5) + (0*0.3) + (-1*0.7) + (1*0.4) = 0.2
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I am new to R and still working on stuffs like `%in%`, `match` and `merge`.

**data**

```
mat <- structure(list(Gene1 = c("1", "0", "-1", "1"), Gene2 = c("0", "-1", "0", "1"), Gene5 = c("-1", "0", "1", "0"), Gene7 = c("1", "1", "1", "0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4"))

score <- structure(list(GeneName = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7"), Score = c("0.5", "0.3", "0.2", "0.6", "0.7", "0.1", "0.4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: If `mat` has dimensions 4x7, we could just directly compute the vectorized dot-product `mat %*% score`. (And you can pad `mat` with missing NA columns for the don't-care genes, to make it 4x7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data in its current state, you can do the following:

```
# get matching values
myVals <- as.numeric(score$Score[match(names(mat), score$GeneName, nomatch=FALSE)])
# Get the dot product for each row
apply(mat, 1, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x) * myVals))
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 
    0.2     0.1     0.6     0.8
```

The first line uses `match` to select the positions of `score` that correspond with the column names of mat. The corresponding values are then extracted with `[`. In the second line, `apply`  calculates the dot product for each row of mat with the extracted values.

Note that your numeric data is stored as characters, so I use `as.numeric` to coerce the vectors for calculation.

---

Given the structure of your data, you would probably be better off storing them as numeric matrices with row and column names.

```
# turn mat into a matrix:
mat2 <- sapply(mat, as.numeric)

# dot product of each row: matrix multiplication
mat2 %*% myVals
     [,1]
[1,]  0.2
[2,]  0.1
[3,]  0.6
[4,]  0.8
```

Comment: @Imo Thanks! Works perfectly! I need to study more about this `apply` function I guess. Seems like very useful and fast.

Comment: `apply` is typically slower than many other methods, but can be useful when you need to do row operations on matrices (or data.frames). The fastest solution for this particular problem, especially if you start with matrices, would be the matrix multiplication method as it uses super fast fortran libraries.

Comment: The whole `apply(mat, 1, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x) * myVals))` line is just a dot-product `mat %*% myVals`. Just here the matrix contents are string and the rownames are annoying, but that just requites a little extra code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get this done fairly efficiently (without loops - apply functions) using `dplyr/tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mat$Sample <- row.names(mat)
row.names(mat) <- NULL

mat %>%
  gather(GeneName, Value, -Sample) %>%
  inner_join(., score) %>%
  group_by(Sample) %>% summarise(score = sum(Value * Score))
```

Output is:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
   Sample score
    <chr> <dbl>
1 Sample1   0.2
2 Sample2   0.1
3 Sample3   0.6
4 Sample4   0.8
```

Comment: Hi! Not exactly got a hold of what's going on here. Can you explain the code? Thanks!

Comment: `gather` creates a long data frame with Gene name and value, `inner_join` keeps common rows by Gene name and brings in the score column corresponding to each gene name, and `group_by / summarise` do aggregate product of value and score per sample. You can execute each individual piece of code and see what is going on.